# SAS: What is the difference between an X Statement and an X Command?

Tags: operating-system, sas

For Windows, there are two separate documentation pages, but it's not clear to me what the distinction is, if any.

[X Command: Windows](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1lye1z610q1rbn1ch6zbpeqcrn2.htm)

[X Statement: Windows](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1vt3ybuz7d0n1n0z1orjvq2ww3x.htm)

The existence of two separate pages implies there is some difference. The X Statement documentation even makes reference to the X Command,

> "There are other ways of running operating environment commands besides
>   the X statement (and the X command) under Windows."

Yet both appear to perform the same role and have the same syntax of `X <'command'>;`.  If they are different, how can one identify the one from the other? Context?

The only explanation I can think of is that the X Statement is the line defined as the characters between the SAS keyword '`X`' and the semi-colon `;`, i.e. `X <command>;` and that the X Command is the `<command>` portion of the X Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements are submitted as part of the code. Like a `LIBNAME` statement or a `DATA` statement.  Commands are typed at the command line of a Display Manager window. Like the `FILE` command or the `WSAVE` command.